# Назначение для Админки Yii2 свой шаблон

Tags: php, yii2

Есть сайт разработанный под yii2, и есть Админка.
На пользовательской части для авторизации пользователей используется стандартный шаблон авторизации, а для админки нужно использовать свой Админский шаблон авторизации. Не могу решить эту проблему. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, Как мне его реализовать?

Comment: Шаблон авторизации? Вы имеете ввиду view для формы авторизации? или что? Или может быть layout?

Comment: layout. Если view буду использовать то header и leftbar будут включены.  Мне нужен чистый layout с полями ввода логина и пароля.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы использовать другой шаблон, в контроллере напишите:

```
$this->layout = 'admin';
```

И создайте новый файл шаблона `view/layouts/admin.php`

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

Если вам нужно перенаправлять на другой адрес для авторизации, то нужно поменять конфиг. Можно сделать отдельный конфиг для админки. Ну или можете в нужном контроллере сделать `beforeAction`, а в нем прописать:

```
Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['admin/sign-in'];
```

Comment: Это то понятно. Я это знаю. Мне нужно в разделе авторизация для админки использовать это. В конфиге yii2 прописан адрес перенаправления по умолчанию site/login а мне нужно, если я веду в строке бр. Site.ru/admin показывался админская авторизация, а не пользовательская. Т.е. Когда не авторизован Правила модуля меня перенаправляют на страницу авторизации.

Comment: Вы хотите узнать "Как перенаправлять на другой адрес"? смотрите выше, в ответе